# Serializing and deserializing Entity Framework version

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

I have a model in my db that has versions, when I `GET` the object the C# version is a `byte[8]` but in Json, the object appears to be a string: `AAAAAAAACXc=` to be precise.

When I do a `POST` from my js app, my controller accepts a dynamic c# object because the data can be of any of derived classes and I need to be able to deal with all objects.

Currently, I'm doing this to deserialize object :

```
... Post([FromBody]dynamic data)
{
    var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data.ToString());

    //This line errors out
    CareTaker careTaker = JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CareTaker>(jsonObj.ToString());
}
```

But I get an error:

> exceptionMessage: "Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'"

because in `CareTaker` class, the `Version` property is defined as a `byte[]` but the json string appears as`AAAAAAAACXc=`..

How do I convert this version string into it's original format of: `[0 0 0 0 0 0 9 119]` ?

Thank you.

I thought I'd manually override this dynamic property value to byte array, so going this route. I've tried converting the string to normal byte array, but it seems to be more than 8 in length, end EF throws validation error saying that it should either be a string or a `byte[]` of length 8...

Comment: Are you using both `Json.NET` and `System.Web.Script.Serialization` for deserialization? Why not using only `Json.NET` to deserialize to `CareTaker`?

Comment: @GeorgeChond oops, I was trying out if I either of them would do any better so this is an artifact from that, the `Json.net` one is just returning null values for all my object so I'm sticking with MS one for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking all mixing JsonConvert and JavaScriptSerializer.

First, instead of deserialize/serialize/deserialize, why don't you use a JToken?

```
var token = JToken.Parse(data.ToString());
```

In this way you have an object like a collection where you can access members and check which type is.

And in this way you can then do

```
var deserObj = token.ToObject<theType>();
```

This will also correct the byte[] problem you have as Json.net will see that the property is a byte array and the data is a base64 string, it will take care of converting the data.

Comment: nope, it's not because there is a ToString, the function only sees a string, nothing else, you have or a very old version or some other class which has the same name, try to use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(data.ToString())

Comment: sorry, ignore my last comment, I had a minor type in my ToString and because it was on a dynamic object, VS was thrown off I think. But this works very well, thank you very much for introducing me to the `JToken`!